# SQL Alchemy update table using list of dicts with bindparam not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform an update based on a list of dictionaries using bindparam, but I'm not sure why this example isn't working:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, exc, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

con_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{login}:{passwd}@{hostname}:{port}/{db}'

engine_str = con_string.format(
    login=login, passwd=pwd, hostname=hostname, port=db_port, db=db_name
)

try:
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    connection = engine.connect()
    session = session(bind=connection)
    Base = declarative_base()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    raise



def bulk_updater(data):
    for i in data:
        print i
    t = Table('demo_table', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    try:
        stm = t.update().where(
            t.c.trigger_service == bindparam('trigger_service')).values={package_name: 'package_name'}
        connection.execute(stm, data)
    finally:
        session.close()

d = [{'package_name': 'something', 'trigger_service': 'somewhere'}, {'package_name': 'somesome', 'trigger_service': 'wherewhere'}]
bulk_updateer(d)
```

**EDIT**

It seems the problem is when using bindparam here, because when i force the value it works perfectly. Still trying to understand why isn't working.

```
t.c.trigger_service == bindparam('trigger_service')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring all the surrounding functionality – and errors – and focusing on the update we can simplify your example to something along the lines of

```
In [2]: t = Table('demo_table', metadata,
   ...:           Column('trigger_service', String()),
   ...:           Column('package_name', String()))

In [5]: stmt = t.update().\
   ...:     where(t.c.trigger_service == bindparam('trigger_service'))
```

which omits the explicit [`values()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update.values) and relies on the automatic invocation of [`bindparam()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) for *package_name*:

> Similarly, `bindparam()` is invoked automatically when working with CRUD statements as far as the “VALUES” portion is concerned.

It works for the SET portion of update statements as well. When trying to execute it there's a very descriptive exception:

```
In [9]: d = [{'package_name': 'something', 'trigger_service': 'somewhere'},
   ...:      {'package_name': 'somesome', 'trigger_service': 'wherewhere'}]

In [10]: conn.execute(stmt, d)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
CompileError: bindparam() name 'trigger_service' is reserved for
  automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this insert/update
  statement.   Please use a name other than column name when using
  bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example, 'b_trigger_service').
```

So the answer is in the exception itself: use a different name for the *trigger_service* `bindparam()`:

```
In [15]: stmt = t.update().\
    ...:     where(t.c.trigger_service == bindparam('b_trigger_service'))

In [16]: d = [{'package_name': 'something', 'b_trigger_service': 'somewhere'},
    ...:      {'package_name': 'somesome', 'b_trigger_service': 'wherewhere'}]

In [17]: conn.execute(stmt, d)
2017-08-09 22:03:12,823 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE demo_table SET package_name=? WHERE demo_table.trigger_service = ?
2017-08-09 22:03:12,823 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (('something', 'somewhere'), ('somesome', 'wherewhere'))
Out[17]: <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0x7fc391b0b748>
```

Comment: I managed to discover the error today as soon i copied the code to my local machine. I'm still not sure why the code isn't throwing any exception when running on the server. Besides accepting your answer as correct, would you mind which errors you found?

Comment: On the road, but the example you've written here contains for example this: `.values={package_name: 'package_name'}`. I suppose that's meant to be a function call instead of an attempt at assignment to the `values` attribute/method.

Comment: I got that out of an example that i found around here. i managed to correct it later. But thanks for pointing that out too.